# Programmatically changing recognizerintent to recognize a language other than English not working

Tags: android, recognizer-intent

I tried both of these ways and the google voice web search is still only recognizing English.

```
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "ja-JP");
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "ja-JP");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ja-JP");
```

Comment: still the same. only recognizing English.

Comment: Check your phone settings and see if the recognizer language supports Japanese. I use ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH instead of web search and has no problem with Japanese.

Comment: Also try ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS to see if Japanese is supported. More details at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS

Comment: u're right. I need to download the language for the recognizerIntent to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String lang_code = "ja-JP";

Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, lang_code);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Hi speak something");
```